# apache expires not working for pyramid server

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, cache, apache-2.2

I have a pyramid server running on EC2 via apache with following configuration -

```
<Directory path_to_virtual_env>
     WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
     Require all granted
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all

     SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain application/x-javascript application/x-font-woff
     BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
     BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
     BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

     ExpiresActive On
     ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
     Header append Cache-Control "public"
</Directory>
```

I am able run Pyramid Server on Port 80 with GZIP compression but as far as expiry module is concerned I get following response for most of the files -

[image: Chrome Network Tab Screenshot]

I have ensured that expires module is running by executing - `sudo a2enmod expires` and `sudo a2enmod headers` yet I get same response as above. I have tried many answers from stackoverflow on this topic but still no success.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Perhaps an errant `.htaccess` file? - Your assertion that you tried lots of strategies from SO is reassuring, but doesn't really help in narrowing down the problem scope for us.

Answer (score 0):

The module you've added will set the expiration time for **files** that Apache serves.

It will not interfere with the expiration headers that are present from your script.

You can test this by moving the `mod_expires` section into your server root location - i.e. not beneath the application prefix - then fetching something like `/robots.txt`, or `/favicon.ico`.

If you want to set expiration headers for dynamic output you should do that in the application itself.